# How to create 2d array c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I need to create 2d array in c++.

I can't do it by `int mas= new int[x][y];` or `auto mas= new int[x][y];`
I need to create an array dynamically like:

```
int x,y
auto mas= new int[x][y];//error - must be const.
```

Please help me.

Comment: You should get a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904304/3d-array-c-using-int-operator/3904484#3904484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to avoid the pain of multidimensional arrays in the first place and use a struct.

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
}

int points = 10;
Point myArray[points];
```

Then to access a value:

```
printf("x: %d, y: %d", myArray[2].x, myArray[2].y);
```

Depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve, though.

Comment: An array of pairs is completely different from a matrix. In one case you have `2*n` values, in the other `n*m` values.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ tool for creating dynamically sized arrays is named `std::vector`. Vector is however one-dimensional, so to create a matrix a solution is to create a vector of vectors.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > mas(y, std::vector<int>(x));
```

It's not the most efficient solution because you pay for the ability to have each row of a different size. You you don't want to pay for this "feature" you have to write your own bidimensional matrix object. For example...

```
template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    int rows, cols;
    std::vector<T> data;

    Matrix(int rows, int cols)
      : rows(rows), cols(cols), data(rows*cols)
    { }

    T& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
        return data[row*cols + col];
    }

    T operator()(int row, int col) const
    {
        return data[row*cols + col];
    }
};
```

Then you can use it with

```
 Matrix<int> mat(y, x);
 for (int i=0; i<mat.rows; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<mat.cols; j++)
     mat(i, j) = (i == j) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int x,y;
x =3;
y = 5;
int ** mas = new int*[x];
for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
   mas[i] = new int[y];
}
```

I think something like this.
Don't forget

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
   delete[] mas[i];
delete[] mas;
```

at the end.

Comment: You forgot the deletion of the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the manipulations yourself.

```
int* mas = new int[x*y];
```

and access [i,j] by:

```
mas[i*y + j] = someInt;
otherInt = mas[i*y +j];
```

Comment: @Charles Bailey: is correct. usually when you define matrix[rows][columns] then the compiler can translate matrix[x][y] to matrix[x*columns +y] and all will work good. but when you just cast it to int** he have no idea how to access matrix[x][y]. he must know the dimensions for that.

Comment: Charles and Roee, thanks for correcting me. I compiled a test code but didn't run it - it indeed causes undefined behavior (namely, crashing...). It looks like I'm a little rusty on pointer arithmetics...

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >  mas(y, std::vector<int>(x));
```