# Writing 2D array to binary file

Tags: c++

The following code is supposed to write a 2D array (quad_array) to a binary file. The code creates the file (quads.dat) but does not write anything to it (0 bytes).

```
XMFLOAT3 * quad_array;
quad_array = new XMFLOAT3 * [quad_width];
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < quad_width; x++) {
    quad_array[x] = new XMFLOAT3[quad_height];
}
// ... fills quad_array with data...
ofstream ofs("quads.dat", std::ofstream::binary);
ofs.open("quads.dat");
streamsize size = sizeof(XMFLOAT3)*quad_height*quad_width;
ofs.write((char*)&quad_array[0][0], size);
ofs.close();
```

Comment: I don't see any 2D arrays in this code.

Comment: There is no need to be snarky, it's a pointer based 2D array. Pointing out it is not contiguous in memory would have been useful.

Comment: I am not being snarky, this is not a 2D array. There's no such thing as a "pointer based 2D array"; what you have is a pointer-to-pointer. Searching for similar question (there are dozens of duplicates of this one on SO!) would have been useful.

Comment: You are clearly caught up in semantics. I suppose "2D array of pointers" is the most precise.

Comment: No, I'm not confused. The most precise is what I wrote: pointer to pointer (to `XMLFLOAT3`). A 2D array of pointers looks like this: `T *arr[width][height];`

Comment: This has nothing to do with confusion, i said semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should remove the

```
  ofs.open("quads.dat");
```

statement, because you already gave the filename at the previous line (constructor).

But that is not enough. You don't have a 2D array, but an array of pointers to arrays, so they are not contiguous in memory.

If `quad_height` and  `quad_width` are compile-time constants, you could use nested [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7944154/841108).

Comment: If I ever design a native/systems programming language, the very first thing I will leave out from the C(++) feature list is implicit conversion between arrays and pointers.

Comment: Thank you, the open command was preventing the writing. Quad_height and quad_width are not compile-time constants. Even if a pointer based 2D array is not wholly contiguous in memory, quad_array[0][0] to quad_array[0][quad_height] is contiguous correct? So, ofs.write((char*)&quad_array[0][0], size); should be writing one of the columns (plus some gibberish)?