# C within C++ code

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have written a C++ application and within it, I need to call a math function that was written in C.  The prototype looks like:

```
void Jacobi_Cyclic_Method(double *eigenvalues, double *eigenvectors, double *A, int n);
```

My problem is that I can't seem to pass the function double * (for instance both eigenvectors and A are multi-dimensional arrays.  The C++ way to pass those things seems to be

```
double [][size]
```

I have read about extern C but I don't think it applies here since I am not interfacing with an object but with source itself.  How can I send that C function my multi-dimensional arrays defined as such:

```
double [100][100] A;
double [100][100] eigenvectors;
double [100] eigenvalues;
```

Trying to compile I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MathEngine::Jacobi_Cyclic_Method(double 
[100], double [100][100], double [100][100], int)’
mathEngine.h:9: note: candidates are: static void    
MathEngine::Jacobi_Cyclic_Method(double*, double*, double*, int)
```

Comment: Are you re-compiling everything, including your math function's implementation, or are you linking to an existing compiled library?  That matters a lot as to whether `extern "C"` matters or not

Comment: The same way that you would do it had your arrays been defined in C.

Comment: You should just be able to pass these values in directly.  A `double[100]` is a `double *`, and so is a `double[100][100]`.  What goes wrong when you try?

Comment: Your C prototype requires one-dimension arrays for eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and A. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am recompiling from it's source.  When I try to compile I edited my post with what I get when I try to compile

Comment: Note that MathEngine is just a class I am using to hold a bunch of static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your C function requires multi-dimensional arrays for some of its parameters and that the prototype is written with pointers to doubles for the array/matrix parameters where the integer parameter indicates the size of each dimension (I guess the matrices are square?).  If this is the case then you can pass a pointer to the first element of each array/matrix like this:

```
Jacobi_Cyclic_Methods(&eigenvalues[0], &eigenvectors[0][0], &A[0][0], 100);
```

Your initial attempt doesn't work because the type of, for instance, `eigenvectors` is `double[100][100]` which decays to `double (*)[100]`, not `double *`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920729/in-c-c-is-char-arrayname-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-or-a-pointe) post addresses the issue of pointers and multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't try this unless the function documentation states that a `double[100][100]` is the right format.  Check if the function requires row-major or column-major matrix layout.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I will try it out when I get home.  Thanks

Comment: This has the exact effect of casting directly to (double *). Both methods let me compile but I still had issues with how the C function thought the memory was laid out vs how it actually was.  That said, this works as a solution to my original post.

Comment: When operating with matrices it's worth remembering that C and C++ store them in row- major order. Iterating over matrices in column-major order can create huge performance problems. Unless the whole matrix fits in a single cache-line you can take a cache-miss every time you increment the column index.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that your `Jacobi_Cyclic_Method` function requires the matrix to be in either column or row major format, where every column/row is stored consecutively in a single, one-dimensional array. E.g. for a row major matrix of size *m x n*, the elements in any given row are stored contiguously and the item in row *i* and column *j* would be at position *i*n+j* (for zero-based indices *i* and *j*). If the matrix is column-major, it would be at position *i+j*m*.

Using multi-dimensional arrays in C/C++ is often not what you want because something like

```
double A[100][100];
```

is not a two-dimensional array, but a single array of length 100 containing pointers to arrays of length 100. Consequently, the rows in `A` are not stored contiguously.

Comment: Well, the method is defined here:  http://code.google.com/p/biaxmc2/source/browse/trunk/montecarlo2/mc2/src/jacobi_cyclic_method.c?spec=svn98&r=98  It appears that it does indeed accept a double[][].

Comment: That's what the comments say, but the code says differently. If it accepted `double[][]`, the argument declaration for the matrix should be `double** A`, not `double* A`. -- BTW, what kind of a person are you to chose such a disrespectful, stupid user-name?!

Comment: Wow!  You know I took the name from someone I saw on a game I used to play a while back and certainly wasn't aware of the chemical warfare aspect.  I was quite confused at your comment here until I looked it up.  I had an avatar of a guy in an orange suit etc, etc.  Certainly no offense intended, I apologize.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: ;-) Glad you didn't choose that name knowing its meaning. Apologies too, for my harsh reaction. Any ways, I generally prefer it if people choose display names related to their real names.