# Writing each word with pointer array

Tags: c

I got a program that split up words. Like if I write "My name is ali"
The program will write

```
Word one: My
Word two: name
word three: is
word four: ali
```

Now I want to add something like

```
int number;
printf("which word do you want to write? number: \n");
scanf("%d",&number)
```

Then if user writes "four" it is suppose to write `ali`
or if they write "two" it is supposed to write `name`.

```
int delaUppText(char input[], char* pekare[])
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    char prevLetter=' ';

    for(i=0; input[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if(prevLetter==' '&&input[i]!=' ')
        {
            pekare[j]=&input[i];
            j++;
        }
        prevLetter=input[i];
    }

    for(i=0; input[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            input[i]=NULL;
        }
    }

    return j;
}

int main()
{
    char input[200];
    char* pekare[100];
    int i, antalPekare;
    char answer = 32;
    int nummer;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Enter a string: ");

        gets(input);

        printf("\n");

        antalPekare = delaUppText(input, pekare);

        for(i=0;i<antalPekare;i++)
        {
            printf("Ord %d: %s\n", i+1, pekare[i]);
        }

        printf("\nWould you like to try again? [Space]/[q]");
        answer = getch();

        if (answer == 32)
        {
         system("cls");
        }
        else if (answer == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }while (answer == 32);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lets say you downvote, please leave a comment on why. I really do not see why this question should be downvoted.

Comment: What's the question? What has the OP tried?

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately compilers don't speak English.

So if your user has to enter "four", then don't expect that `scanf("%d",&number)` will recognize the word "four". it will recognize only digits, so your user must enter "4", or you must parse the input to learn what number-word he entered. How about input in German?

Answer (score 0):

### 1

Looking over your code I find that there are much better ways of doing this.
 One such way is the use of **strtok** you can find more about it here.

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
> char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
> ```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Or you can also use **strsep**

> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
> ```

### 2

Now if you want to make it work with what you have. You need to use heap memory. aka [malloc, calloc]. The reason is once you return to your main the stack of the program will be reduced and the memory on the stack that was once in you program will be no more. **Now if you use the heap then you should also make sure you free the memory once and only once.**

For the rest of the problem I am going to leave you to read this.

[In C/C++, is char* arrayName[][] a pointer to a pointer to a pointer OR a pointer to a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920729/in-c-c-is-char-arrayname-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-or-a-pointe)