# Passing parameters to a functions

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I created my test function:
`void test(double** matrix);`

I want to pass to this function variable as `double matrix[2][2] = {{1,2},{2,3}};`. But my evil compiler writes: `cannot convert «double (*)[2]» to «double**» for argument «1» to «void test(double**)»`.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Comply with the evil compiler's order. You can't substitute a `double[][]` to a `double**` because the memory layouts are different. You'll need to allocate your rows with `new` or find another way (hint: `vector`).

Comment: You need to read a basic C language guide.

Comment: Mutidemensional arrays != jagged arrays. Jagged arrays are double** and must be allocated with new or malloc, and are an array of pointers. Multidimensional arrays are one continuous memory block that can be indexed funny.

Comment: **Four** ways to [pass 2-D matrix in c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566661/c-dynamic-array-initalization-with-declaration/17567663#17567663)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a pointer to multidimensional array: C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904224/declaring-a-pointer-to-multidimensional-array-c)

Comment: Thank for answers! It was strange for me, because when I do this with one-dimensional arrays I have not problems.

Closed.

Comment: [Also read this.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types of the arguments and the parameters have to agree (or
at least be compatible).  Here, you have a `double[2][2]`, and
you want to pass it to a `double**`.  The types are unrelated:
an array of arrays is not an array of pointers (which would
convert to a pointer to a pointer).

If you really want to pass a `double [2][2]`, you'll have to
declare the parameter as a `double (*matrix)[2]`, or (better yet),
a `double (&matrix)[2][2]`.

Of course, if you're using C++, you'll want to define a `Matrix`
class, and use it.

Comment: `void test(double (&matrix)[2][2])` gives `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token` (at least on C) is for C++?

Comment: @DavidRF Yes.  It's purely C++.  I hadn't noticed that the question was tagged both---the answer in C has to be `double (*matrix)[2]`.