# What is this representation of a pointer to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've just come across this program that deals with multidimensional arrays. While I've got the gyst of it, there's a particular notation that I'm not sure of.

The idea is to pass a pointer to the column of a multidimensional array, because 2-Dim arrays do not require you to mention the number of rows in the 2D matrix. So, a pointer pm to the column of the 2D matrix is passed as: `int (*pm)[COLUMN]`

Here's the full program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const int ROW  = 2;
const int COL=3;

void fill_array(int (*pm)[COL], int row);
void display_array(int m[][COL], int row);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */

    int i,j;
    int m[ROW][COL];

    //CALL function to enter elements
    fill_array(m,ROW);

    //display
    display_array(m,ROW);
    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int (*pm)[COL], int row)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("Please fill the array's content: \n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
        {
            printf("\n m[%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &pm[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void display_array(int m[][COL], int row)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("\n Array's contents: \n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COL;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", m[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the representation of a pointer to an array. What I mean is I'm not familiar with this notation where a pointer is just appended to the array. Could someone please throw some light on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: `void fill_array(int (*pm)[COL], int row);`is the same as `void fill_array(int pm[][COL], int row);`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904224/declaring-a-pointer-to-multidimensional-array-and-allocating-the-array

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed by value to a function then it is converted to a pointer to its first element. According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

If you pass this array

```
int m[ROW][COL];
```

to a function that it is converted to pointer to its first element that is in turn an array of type `int[COL]`. A pointer to this array will look like

```
int ( * )[COL]
```

If you will dereference this pointer you will get one-dimensional array of type `int[COL]`

SO for example if you declared a pointer to a one dimensional array like

```
int ( *pm )[COL]
```

then expression

```
*pm
```

has type of `int[COL]`

Expression `*pm` is equivalent to `pm[0]` As `pm[0]` is an array then you may apply the subscript operator a second time `pm[0][0]` and will get the first element of type `int` of the two-dimensional arra.

Answer (score 1):

As an argument of a function, `int m[][COL]` is equivalent to `int (*m)[COL]`, in the same way `int v[]` is equivalent to `int *v`. In both cases, `m` is treated as a pointer to an integer array of size `COL`.

The important bit is that `*m` (dereferencing `m`) gives you the first array (just like `*v` gives you the first element in that vector). And pointer arithmetic on `m` works as expected, e.g. `*(m+1)` gives you the second array. As a consequence, you can index `m` as if it was a two-D array (`m[i][j]`) inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

I am still relatively new to C but I believe it is a pointer to an array of pointers. The only way I know how to make a dynamic 2 dimensional array is like that.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if I can say the real truth is that in C/C++ there is no array more than allocated consecutive space in the memory. There is a pointer that points to the beginning of the allocated memory block. in that case if you have array of [10] int elements, the allocated space is about sizeof(int)*10 and the pointer points to the first element. Because of that you could easily increments ++ and decrements -- to move around.

With dimensional arrays it is easy to pass the pointer(s) to their first elements and increment around to columns. However, you could easily work with array[2][3] with a single pointer. You just need to multiply 2 * 3 to capture the whole allocated memory block.

Comment: You are wrong, C/C++ have arrays more over even multidiemnsional arrays.

Comment: Well, we are talking for the standard arrays. They are actually allocated space shifted each time. because of that pointers and arrays are so related to each other.

Comment: By the way, you can check Jerry Chain course of programming paradigms http://see.stanford.edu/errors/default.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/see/courseinfo.aspx

Comment: It is no matter how arrays are realized in one or other language.  Nevertheles an array is not a pointer in C/C++.

Comment: Take into account that it is not me who downvoted your answer. But in any case your answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I do not mean that it is a pointer. I meant that pointer is actually the beginning of the array. The whole idea was to explain why the pointers and arrays are so strongly related in this two languages.  Cheers!