# Declaring multidimensional floating or unsigned dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can I initialize a floating or unsigned multidimensional dynamic array in C++?

I tried the following and got a seg fault,

```
float **array = NULL:

array = new float* [rows];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    array[i] = new float [cols];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't enough code there to diagnose the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: please show at least where you write something into the array (and eliminate the duplicate definition of array)

Comment: @onie I'd go ahead and say that you should really use a vector or similar abstraction. It will save you many headaches.

Comment: Use a one-dimensional array (`std::vector`) and stay away from `new` and `float**`.

Comment: `std::vector<float> array(rows * cols);` or if you really don't want to abstract it `std::vector<std::vector<float>> array(rows,  std::vector<float>(cols));`

Comment: `float **array = NULL:` followed by `float** array = new float* [rows];` looks like you might be having a [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) problem. No way to be sure, though, without the aforementioned MCVE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring a pointer to multidimensional array and allocating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904224/declaring-a-pointer-to-multidimensional-array-and-allocating-the-array)

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close this as a duplicate of [Declaring a pointer to multidimensional array and allocating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904224/declaring-a-pointer-to-multidimensional-array-and-allocating-the-array/3904306#3904306)

When declaring a multi-dimensional array `arrary[col][rows]`, `[col]` needs to be constant where `[rows]` doesn't have to be. This notation should work to resolve the issue.

```
const int col = someval;
const int row = someval;

int (*array)[row] = new int[col][row];
```

Otherwise you can use a `single` dimensionally array such that it has `[row*col]` elements. From there you would have to do the calculation when `indexing` the flat array for a `2D structure`.

Typically a single array and double for looping would look like this:

```
type *array = new type[row * col];

for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ ) {
        array[i * col + j];
    }
}
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate in a fairly traditional manner for a given number of `pointers` and and then a given number of `float` assigning a pointer to each allocated block of `float` using the [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and then using a corresponding [delete expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) to regain the memory allocated to avoid a *memory leak* when that allocated memory is no longer needed. It is loosely analogous to using `malloc` and `free`, but there is a large difference in what goes on under the hood.

For example, given your *pointer-to-pointer-to-float*, you could construct a short example to illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS 10

int main (void) {

    float **array = NULL;               /* pointer to pointer to float */

    array = new float*[ROWS];           /* allocate ROWS pointers to float */
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        array[i] = new float[COLS];     /* allocate COLS floats */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            array[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << array[i][j];
        cout << "\n";
        delete[] array[i];              /* delete COLS floats */
    }
    delete[] array;                     /* delete ROWS pointers to float */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_new_del
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

You must take care to always preserve a pointer to the memory you allocate and to `delete` the memory you allocate when it is no longer needed to prevent leaking memory. It is also imperative that you run your code that allocates and deletes memory through a memory error checking program to insure you have used the memory correctly and that all memory has been freed when it is no longer needed. For Linux, `valgrind` is the normal choice. All you need to it is run your code through it, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/array_new_del
==1206== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1206== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1206== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1206== Command: ./bin/array_new_del
==1206==
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20
   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
==1206==
==1206== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1206==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1206==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 74,208 bytes allocated
==1206==
==1206== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1206==
==1206== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1206== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always verify that you have freed all memory you allocate and that there are no memory errors.